# How do i use the length of a tuple inside a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to see if a tuple inside a tuple only has the number 2, any number of times

```
def check_tupl(tpl):
    for i in range(len(tpl)):
        tuple(tpl[i])                   
        for i in range(len(tpl[i][i])):
            if tpl[i][i]==2:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

it shows me this error message

builtins.TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: have you tried just using `in` ?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have two nested for loops that both use the variable name `i`.

Comment: I've tried using in and also changed i to e but then it  said local variable 'e' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 3):

We can use `any` and `all` to check for this efficiently.

```
def check_tupl(tpls):
    return any(all(v == 2 for v in tpl) for tpl in tpls)
```

Comment: this is awesome, i was thinking of a list style comprehension but was havnig to then call to bool to try to get the return value. i need to remember any and all

Comment: As per the latest edit to the question, it should be `any(set({2}) == set(tpl) for tpl in tpls)`

Answer (score 1):

Its because here you get a int value and you check for its length `len(tpl[i][i])`.

Try this (its kind of self explanatory):

```
def check_tupl(tpl):
    for tuple in tpl:                  
        for i in tuple:
            if i==2:
                return True
    return False
```

Or with using `in`:

```
def check_tupl(tpl):
    for tuple in tpl:   
        if 2 in tuple:               
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: This doesn't look right to me. If I do `tuples = ((1,1),(1,2))`, both of these approaches give me False.

Comment: I think the `return False` needs to be two indentation levels less and there's no need for the `else` clause.

Comment: the approach is right just needs the variables edited to use the tpl name passed as the parameter of the function

Comment: Sorry I messed up with the names, should be ```tpl``` instead of ```tuples```

Comment: yeah thats better

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the title is in sync with the users goal.

> How do i use the length of a tuple inside a tuple?

vs

> I'm trying to see if a tuple inside a tuple only has the number 2, any
>   number of times

Regarding find the number 2, how bout giving recursion a try

```
def find2(tpl):
    for element in tpl:

        if isinstance(element, tuple):
            return find2(element)
        else:
            if element == 2:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```